# Android Studio WebView URL JavaScript won't load

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, kotlin

This is the sample of my project I can't load my design.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add web chrome client after enabling Java Script

```
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```